# Parent Controller vs Parent resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am confusing about weather to use parent state's `controller` or`resolve` to validate(user authentications) .
 Here is sample code.

```js
          .state('dashboard.action.seller.manageproduct', {
                url: '/manageProduct',
                template: '<div ui-view></div>',
                abstract : true,
                controller : function(userRolesFactory){ 
           
              /*
                       Here i can resolve or validate all the user roles and make decision wether to go it's                            chaild state or not for all it chaild states
                       */
          },
               resolve: {
                    userRoles: ['userRolesFactory', function(userRolesFactory) {
                       /*
                       Here also i can resolve or validate all the user roles and make decision wether to go it's                            chaild state or not for all it chaild states
                       */
                    }]
                }
                

            })
            .state('dashboard.action.seller.manageproduct.add', {
                url: '/addProduct',
               // templateUrl: 'module/dashboard/actiontab/seller/manageproduct/view/addProduct.html',
               // controller: 'fos.dashboard.actiontab.seller.manageproduct.addproductController',
                requireLogin: true
            })
            .state('dashboard.action.seller.manageproduct.edit', {
                url: '/editProduct',
              //  templateUrl: 'module/dashboard/actiontab/seller/manageproduct/view/editProduct.html',
             //   controller: 'fos.dashboard.actiontab.seller.manageproduct.editProductController',
                params: {
                    product: null
                },
                requireLogin: true
            })
```

My doubts are :

- Which one best suitable for validations (`controller` level or in `resolve`).
- And i **don't want to show my child state's template before all the validation**.
- In future i might do so many validation.

And i know **sequence of execution**.

Comment: I would go for the resolve level and inject it as a local dependency in the controller. If you do it in you controller directly the app would already render without waiting for the validation.

Comment: @Mikey you are right , but my parent state is abstract and it doesn't have any template  and it just place holder for child template. All about my question is at it's child state rendering.